# I need to set and send value of slider after onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using material PrettoSlider I need to set on change properly so if any value gets change I am able to submit that value but what happening right now if I change something means if I click one time I will get value null if I click two times in same value then value get the print I need to set onChnage using formik and need to set field value properly so if I submit then that change value gets submitted whatever value get to change it storing in **event.target.ariaValueNow**
how can I set Field values properly

```
export default function CustomizedSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const ruleForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      partialNameMatchThreshold: 40
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography gutterBottom>pretto.fr</Typography>
      <PrettoSlider
        onChange={(event) => {
          console.log("Number change ", event.target.ariaValueNow);
          ruleForm.setFieldValue(event.target.ariaValueNow);
        }}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        aria-label="pretto slider"
        defaultValue={ruleForm.values.partialNameMatchThreshold}
        marks={marks}
        name="partialNameMatchThreshold"
      />
      <Button
        onSubmit={ruleForm.handleSubmit}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
      >
        Commit Changes
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wb53c)

Answer (score 0):

We should not be using the `event` to capture the selected value . There is a second argument provided by the onChange method which holds the actual selected value.

```
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
```

we need to use the **newValue** instead of event.

Formik's setFieldValue takes 2 arguments , one is the field which you need to update and the other is the value to update .

```
ruleForm.setFieldValue("partialNameMatchThreshold", newValue);
```

Slider component needs to read the value from the Formik to keep the value in sync . So we need to make the slider as a controlled component . Add this new value prop to the slider

```
value={ruleForm.values.partialNameMatchThreshold}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uju2b?file=/demo.js)